# Trouble deploying Unity game to Xbox One dev mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox, xbox-one

It is a MacBook Pro running El Capitan v10.11.4. I am running Windows 10 on a Parallels VM. I have Visual Studio 2015 update 2 installed. The Visual Studio environment is set to Master x64 Remote Machine. It seems to building fine, but it is having trouble connecting to the Xbox. This is the error I'm getting.

> DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping
>   stage 'Connecting to the device 'XboxOne'.':  MissingMethodException -
>   Method not found: 'Boolean
>   Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity.RemoteDevice.Ping()'.

**Edit**

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

**Edit 1**

I am also able to ping the Xbox IP from Windows 10. But Visual Studio does not recognize the Xbox.

Comment: This is the second time you are asking this question. You provided more info this time. What is your MBP make year? What model number?

Comment: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: My solution is to install Windows 10 through Bootcamp. It will run very much well and this problem will likely be gone. MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) supports Windows 10.

Comment: I thought of this too. I was just hoping I wouldn't have to do it. (I really like Parallels)

Comment: There are many services running on Windows. By using Parallels VM, you are emulating all those services. If you install Windows 10 directly with Bootmcamp,  there are less chances you will have problems like this and this is likely the problem. I am telling you this because I am also running Windows 10 on a Mac Hardware. I ran into problems with emulators but by using bootcamp, all those problems went away. If you go with this route, please notify me. I want to know if this solved the problem.

Comment: Alright. I will do it. Let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was using the wrong SDK. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the wrong Windows SDK.

[image]

When installing Visual Studio Update 2, it asks if you want to install the Windows 10 SDK with it. This is the wrong SDK. What you need is the Windows 10 SDK preview.

Here is the link.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615097

Comment: ID? Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes. The SDK that comes with VS is not the correct one.

Comment: Nice. Never  heard of a problem like this before. Congrats.

Comment: @gjttt1 I have to wait two days before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not has this error, try these five things:

Try making sure all your DLL files are up to date,

Make sure you're connected to the internet

Make sure you have a secure connection

If you have a Native Windows machine try it on that.

Try reinstalling the remote on Parallels VM.

If all else fails, try reinstalling Parallels.

I cannot think of anything else :/

Hope this helps :-)

*~Coolq*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the problem is network related as @Programmer said. I am going to try it on bootcamp.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the answer I've written here :

[Xbox one dev mode and Unity free version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240153/xbox-one-dev-mode-and-unity-free-version/37374164#37374164)

Btw to deploy on XboxOne you will need Windows 10 I'm assuming you are running it on you MAC using parallels / Boot camp etc.